# where is the core dump file when Bazel test failed

Tags: c++, bazel

I am new to bazel. When I ran bazel test for C++ unit test, test failed with the message:
external/bazel_tools/tools/test/test-setup.sh: line 310: 25058 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) "${TEST_PATH}" "$@" 2>&1

But I cannot find the core dump file. Where is the core dump file?

Comment: You might need to enable core dumps with `ulimit`. Otherwise dumps are usually created in the current directory of the process

Comment: `systemd-coredump` may be helpful here. Then you can use `coredumpctl` to list and inspect the latest coredumps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install systemd-coredump and also zstd.
before launching `bazel test`, set the ulimit to unlimited

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Then run your test with `-c dbg`

```
bazel test -c dbg :target
```

So that if your code crashed

```
coredumpctl list
TIME                            PID   UID   GID SIG COREFILE  EXE

Wed 2024-03-20 08:19:17 CET  1747893 1314012044 1314000513  11 present   /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/deadbeef/execroot/PJ/bazel-out/k8-dbg/bin/target/targetexe
```

look the info within coredumpctl

```
coredumpctl info PID # here was 1747893
```

you will see that systemd cath it inside /var/lib/systemd/coredump/

Now if it has a suffix zst, it means it has been compressed, to decompress it use zstd

```
zstd coredumpfile.zst -o ./core
```

Then you will be able to check with gdb the backtrace

```
gdb exefile -c ./core
```

:)
Karim